# Number of parameters in method

Tags: java, selenium, refactoring

I have Selenium test which fills a form. I have a method for it but this method has overgrown in terms of number of parameters -

```
 newMerchantPage.addEditMerchant(merchantDomain, merchantName,
            merchantCategory, true, merchantDescription, merchantNotes,
            merchantTags, true, true, false, false, merchantTitle,
            additionalDescription, merchantHeading, dummyCouponLink, true);
```

There are only Strings and boolean.
I was thinking to use collection and then iterate through collection in called method to do some more processing. Though yet not sure if this is the way to go about. Any recommendations?

MODIFIED METHOD:

After implementing couple of sugggestions my method (of a different method) call looks like -

```
ContactPage contactPage = new ContactPage(driver); 
setContactFormData(); 
contactPage.setName(name).setEmailAddress(emailAddress).setSubject(subject).setM‌ ​essage(message); 
contactPage.submitContactForm(contactPage);
```

submitContactForm in turn calls different utility methods. How bad does it look? Especially the last line (method call on object and same object being passed as argument) ?

Comment: Ouch.  I'm not sure how the rest of your code is designed, but it seems like many of the parameters share a common theme (they are properties of a merchant).  Could you perhaps create a merchant object that encapsulates these properties, and pass the merchant object instead?

Comment: I guess aioobe and you are talking same thing :)

Comment: Great minds think alike I guess. :)

Answer (score 5):

One common approach is to wrap the parameters in a class. This class could then provide set-methods which return `this` to allow for a nice chaining. (See [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for a good example.)

**Example:**

```
MerchantData data = new MerchantData();   // initialize with sensible defaults

data.setDomain("example.com")
    .setName("Some Name")
    .setTags("tag1, tag2);

newMerchantPage.addEditMerchant(data);
```

Comment: yup. and a bit easier to decipher which argument corresponds to which parameter. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using Selenium server (or RC).

The suggestions for wrapping the data up into a Merchant class are all good and make sense, especially from pure Java coding point of view.

However, your main point of concern here in Selenium is the form you are filling, rather that the merchant domain object.

Maybe you could then break your method up into smaller methods such as 
openMerchantForm(...)
typeNameInMerchantForm(...)
chooseMerchantCategory(...)

and so on, depending on what type of control is being set on the form. That will reflect the behaviour you are testing rather than setting the domain objects directly etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had it on my mind but did not mention it thinking I would screw the discussion

Comment: I think it makes sense to do it this way. You are trying to simulate the behaviour of filling the form. If you were writing a jUnit test then it would be a different story and a domain object would have made more sense. I think  people are missing the point that this is a selenium fixture and what selenium is used for...

Comment: Some thing else clicked on my mind, I will have small methods to interact with those elements on form and then these all could be called from one method when I need to submit the form. Yet still using the "test data design" described by "aioobe" what do you say?

Comment: You could do that alright, but do you need to call them again when submitting the method? In other words would it not be 1. set all those value in fields on your form 2. submit. Whatever is on the other side (web server I assume?) should look after the rest.

Comment: I see that, and yes I mean the same

Comment: ok I did this, I did not keep a different class for object and used page object instead. from my another example -

        ContactPage contactPage = new ContactPage(driver);
       
        setContactFormData();
        contactPage.setName(name).setEmailAddress(emailAddress).setSubject(subject).setMessage(message);       
        contactPage.submitContactForm(contactPage);

submitContactForm in turn calls different utility methods. How bad does it look? Especially the last line (method call on object and same object being passed as argument) ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe - write a class `Merchant`, create an instance with the *method value* and pass the instance instead?

```
newMerchantPage(Merchant merchant);
```

The advantage: you can keep the test parameters in files and do something like:

```
Merchant merchant = new Merchant();
merchant.populate(File testdata, int record);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a class that is if the parameters you specify belong to something same,then pass the object as the parameter.

Comment: could you explain in plain english? and I did not do -1